# How to do something when I swipe right in a viewpager ( React native )

Tags: react-native

I used viewpager to show information people like this:

[image]

I want to swipe left to show the next people and swipe right to add in favorite list.
But in viewpager swiping right is showing previous people.
How can I do it?

Comment: Share to us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simulation they have shown in their documentation [Simulation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager#ios). You can find 2 buttons "next" and "prev". This example link [ViewPagerExample](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/blob/master/example/ViewPagerExample.js) shows how those 2 buttons work in which you could achieve callbacks triggered for either left or right swipes.